# AngularJS only works if repeatedly refresh page

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Here I try to fetch names and id's of trailers in trailer table into the multi-select. When the page loaded for the first time the data in select not appearing, but if I repeatedly refresh the page then data in multi-select will appear
Code of View

```
<body ng-app="movApp">
    <select ng-controller="movList" ng-init="GetMovie()" class="selectpicker"
            multiple data-live-search="true" id="opts" name="opts">
         <option ng-repeat="x in Trailer" value={{x.trailerid}}>{{x.mov_name}}
         </option>
     </select>
</body>
```

Code in javascript

```
var app = angular.module('movApp', []);
app.controller('movList', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.GetMovie = function () {
        $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "/Ajaxx/GetFilm"
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.Trailer = response.data;
        }, function () {
            alert("Error");
        })
    };
})
```

code in controller

```
 public ActionResult GetFilm()
    {
        return Json(db.Trailers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: `$scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.Trailer = response.data 
    });` should work no? I guess the problem here is a race condition

Comment: @sertsedat Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) $apply has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to $apply is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or when working with third-party library callbacks.

Comment: The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. See [AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#overview).

Comment: Please include the code for the `data-live-search` directive. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).